# Question with link to the public website

Tags: discussion

From time to time, I come across a question containing a link to a public website. Most of the time, it is the OP's website.

The latest example is [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609567/flickering-button-on-hover).

OP provide some *Javascript* and *CSS* to explain his problem but he also provide a link to the public website where the problem is.

Is it something good to do ?

I think that this is not appropriate. It is kinda like an advertising and it does not help to understand his problem. We have to look ourselves in the developer console to find the problematic code.

Should I flag it as **spam** because it promotes a product ? If not, what should I do and why ?

Answer (score 4):

1. If the problem the OP is asking about occurs on the page linked to, presumably it will be fixed once a solution is found, and henceforth the link will not add anything of value to the question anymore and becomes superfluous noise.
2. If the link is *the only* indication of a problem description, it's an incomplete question and deserves immediately nuking. If the link is provided *in addition* to an otherwise complete question, it's not much of a problem.
3. If the linked-to site clearly *promotes a product*, it falls under the category of spam and deserves deletion. If it's just someone's personal blog, I'd give the benefit of the doubt.

Either way, the link hardly serves any purpose and should not be there to begin with. Decide with good conscience whether it's really spam, or just a misguided question. Then either edit the question to remove noise, or really flag as spam. Please *don't* flag as spam reflexively; unless it really is spam the flag will be declined.

Answer (score 2):

If it promotes a product, it should be marked as spam. But even if it doesn't, the question will not be useful if someday the website breaks. The question should contain all essential information to reproduce the problem, without relying on external resources that might be unavailable someday.